# How do I get a class' identifier from storyboard in code?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

How do I retrieve a class' identifier value which was set in storyboard? In the code, I'd like to see if the identifier equals a certain string.

Comment: Where in the storyboard did you set it?  (Which field?)

Comment: I clicked on the view controller, went to attributes inspector and entered it in the first one (which is labeled Identifier).

Comment: `NSString* vcClass = NSStringFromClass(viewController.class);`

Comment: I just tried that, and made an if statement to check and it didn't work. `if ([vcClass  isEqual: @"1"])`. One view controller's Identifier is `1` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Storyboard ID? if so, a class does not have this ID specifically, this is only associated with a viewcontroller that is made in the storyboard, you cant have a class and find out the storyboard ID for it, because a class could be used in multiple storyboards and/or multiple viewcontrollers within a storyboard so doesnt really make sense to look up the ID in that way. what you could do is go

```
UIViewController *VC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheViewControllerID"];

if([VC isKindOfClass[YourClass class]]){

    ...
}
```

but these seems like a very inefficient way of what you are trying to achieve, im sure there could be another way of going about what you are doing, but i dont fully know what your reason for doing this is, so i cant really help with that

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's not a view controller. It's a WKInterfaceController. I changed the first part, but that didn't work. Is this possible with WatchKit?

Comment: unfortunately i have not used watch kit at all yet so i dont know